# How to run tests filtered with tags with cucumber-jvm and gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle, cucumber-jvm

I work with cucumber for some time now, and now I want to migrate test suite usage to gradle from maven.

I managed to prepare the project covering the basic usage, running tests, having the results etc. 
The last piece I am missing is ability to only run the tests filtered on specific tag.
Running acceptance tests is done with product flavor:

```
productFlavors {
    uats {
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.paddy.cuespton.cuespton.test.Instrumentation"
    }

    full {
        applicationId "com.paddy.app.cuespton"
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

Which enables me to run tests with task:

```
./gradlew connectedAndroidTestUatsDebug
```

Is is possible to add param with tag to this task to run specific tests only?

I tried to use
https://github.com/samueltbrown/gradle-cucumber-plugin/ plugin which should in theory solve this issue, but I cannot get it running with Android due to language incompatibility.

Here is repo on which I am working,
https://github.com/paddyzab/espresso-cucumber-sandbox.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Didn't try this cucumber-plugin but assuming that we have similar setup you can do the following ([sample repo](https://github.com/Ghedeon/GradleTestPoc)):

1) define corresponding buildConfigField for the uats flavor:

```
Uats {
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.quandoo.gradletestpoc.test.Instrumentation"

        // passing instrumentation parameters
        buildConfigField "String", "TAGS", "\"${getTagsProperty()}\""
    }
```

2) define getTagsProperty() method:

```
 def getTagsProperty() {
     return project.hasProperty("tags") ? project.getProperties().get("tags") : ""
 }
```

3) Handle passed tag in onCreate() method of your custom instrumentation class:

```
private static final String TAGS_KEY = "tags";
......
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);

    // Reading runner params
    String tags = BuildConfig.TAGS;
    if (!tags.isEmpty()) {
        bundle.putString(TAGS_KEY, tags);
    }

    instrumentationCore.create(bundle);
    start();
}
```

4) Run

```
./gradlew connectedAndroidTestUatsDebug -Ptags="@bar"
```

Enjoy!